# Python2: Installing json_util

Tags: json, python-2.7, package, bson

I used to import json_util from bson:

```
from bson import json_util
```

Now I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name json_util
```

How can I install json_util now?

Answer (score 10):

Did you do?

`pip install bson`

which isntalls this 3rd party package which does not include all the goodies found in MongoDB's package

https://pypi.org/project/bson/

json_util (and a host of other utils) are provided in MongoDB Inc's pymongo package.

`pip install pymongo`

https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/

As noted on the pymongo pypi page

> Do not install the “bson” package from pypi. PyMongo comes with its
>   own bson package; doing “easy_install bson” installs a third-party
>   package that is incompatible with PyMongo.

some distros package MongoDB's bson package 
You might be on RHEL derivative since you're looking at py27.  EPEL has a slightly out of date version you can install with

`yum install python-bson`

http://fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net/fedora-epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p/python-bson-2.5.2-4.el7.x86_64.rpm

mainline ubuntu also packages it (and also separates the C module into the -ext package)

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-bson

`apt-get install python-bson python-bson-ext`

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [this issue](https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/19) and explained in [the detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52921055/3808882), the quick fix is to

```
pip uninstall bson
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo
```